# tox.ini environment with multiple dependencies

Tags: python-3.x, tox

I am trying to specify multiple dependencies in my `tox.ini` file based on [this example in the docs](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html?highlight=v#generating-environments-conditional-settings). Here is my `tox.ini` file

```
[tox]
envlist = {py27,py36}-dj{a,b}

[testenv]
deps =
    pytest
    dja: Django
    djb: numpy, pandas
commands = ...
```

As you can see the environment `djb` has multiple dependencies listed on the same line.

When I run `tox` using

```
tox -e py36-djb
```

I get this error message

```
djb installdeps: numpy,pandas
ERROR: invocation failed (exit code 1), logfile: /.../.tox/djb/log/djb-1.log
```

I think the problem is that (for `djb`) multiple dependencies are listed on the same line, but I'm not sure if there is an alternative method to install multiple python packages into **only** that environment.

How can I specify multiple dependencies for one environment (`djb`) in `tox.ini`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try space instead of comma:

```
[testenv]
deps =
    djb: numpy pandas
```

Or newline:

```
[testenv]
deps =
    djb:
        numpy
        pandas
```

Or list the dependencies separately:

```
[testenv]
deps =
    djb: numpy
    djb: pandas
```

Or put the dependencies into a file `req.txt`:

```
echo "\
numpy
pandas" > req-djb.txt
```

and install them:

```
[testenv]
deps = -rreq-djb.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! Bizarely, it seems the newline and space options didn't work for me...they gave the same error message as in the OP. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with `python3.6.8` and just upgraded `tox` to `3.13.2`. The listing of dependencies separately worked just fine...thanks.